# I have my full special database from xampp how can i use this on wordpress?

Tags: database, local-installation, xampp

The issue I built a database on xampp, but I did this when I was use a normal website (not on wordpress) and one of tables is for users' accounts.

The fields in users' table are username, password, emails and more, but not all have same privileges, only one or two can control anything and not all is active.

"So, How can I force wordpress on my local to use this table or should let wordpress system create its own tables and accounts for some issues?"

*To be honest, my database is full and big and more than 50 tables and I can't cancel it.*

---

Note: This is my first time I use wordpress, and I searched on google but didn't get what I want!, so if my question has some little problems just comment.

Answer (score 0):

Use the wordpress database, without any modifications. If your current database is too big, you can try to export / import users.

Comment: Isn't it same thing?, installing WordPress DB in my old like import my old DB into WP DB.

Comment: Was the old one WordPress database also?

Comment: No, but I still use my current, and if I installed new WP DB in the same version of xampp beside my current, it will be the same!

Comment: In short, I want make new website in wordpress and move my current DB to the new website

Comment: WordPress should use it's own database and that's it. Anything else might be a recipe for a disaster.

Comment: In this case, do you advise to me build other web admin page to other users and use WP admin to who just have privileges to design and write news/articles ?

Comment: Because there are some services like write posts, emails, photo edits, branches and their data, and not all users have same privileges .. and those not in WP admin !